# jQuery-UI's selectmenu is not following the scroll motion when it is inside an overflown div

Tags: overflow, jquery-ui-selectmenu

When I am placing the jQuery selectmenu inside a div that has a CSS property `overflow: scroll` and is smaller then its content, then the dropdown menu is not following the scrolling inside the overflown div.

See the example here

https://codepen.io/Nighel123/pen/gZeQVd?editors=1000

I have found a way to fix it with this code:

```
$(".demo").scroll(function(){
  $( "#salutation" ).selectmenu( "open" );
});
```

But I think this is not the best way to fix the problem since the dropdown does not seem to follow the select element precisely when I am trying the code on my computer. Additionally the dropdown menu opens when I am scrolling inside the overflown div, what is also not the expected behavior of a dropdown.

I also tried to trigger the scroll event of the window object, when the overflown div gets scrolled to fire the positioning methods of the jQuery dropdown menu. But this did not work at all.

I would like to follow the dropdown menu follow my select item more precisely with the scrolling of the overflown div. And maybe also get some less ugly hack compared to what I did above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the appendTo method of the jQuery-UI selectmenu. Just append the dropdown menu to the div that is being scrolled and it works!